# Slicing top and bottom two lines

Tags: javascript, xml, slice

I want to remove the first and last two lines from the following XML. I am using the following method to omit just the first top and last line, how can I amend it to remove the top two and last two lines? So, to remove node1 and node2.

```xml
<node1>
 <node2>
  <context>
    <FirstName>barb</FirstName>
    <LastName>tor</LastName>
  </context>
 </node2>
</node1>
```

```js
var xml ='<node1><node2><context><FirstName>David</FirstName><LastName>Test</LastName></context></node2></node1>';

const innerStart = xml.indexOf(">") + 1;
const innerEnd   = xml.lastIndexOf("<");
const inner      = xml.slice(innerStart, innerEnd);

console.log(inner)
```

Comment: Is your XML given as a string or as nodes? If nodes, I would look into using `document.querySelector()` and `element.replaceWith()`.

Comment: Never try to parse XML as a string; always use an XML-based API.  Failure to follow that well-established guidance creates brittle code that will likely break for you or your successors on unanticipated but perfectly well-formed variations in the XML.  There are many XML-based libraries; the duplicate link suggests XPath in JS, since you're using JS and XPath is an easy, declarative, standard way to specify an element or attribute in XML.